# My function is deleting a different row to the one I intended, Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

When I press remove, it removes the last charity in the database that belongs to the current user.

View (Button that deletes):

```
<a href="#"> <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btnPopover" data-
toggle="popover" data-placement="top"> Remove </button> </a>
```

View (JS that is called):

```
function ConfirmDelete()
{
    true;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.btnPopover').popover(
    {
        html: 'true',
        title: '<strong> Are you sure you want to Remove? </strong>',
        content: '<form style="display: inline;" action="{{ 
        URL::to('remove', array($favourite->id)) }} "> <button class = "btn 
        btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok" onclick="return 
        ConfirmDelete()"> Yes </button> </form> <button class = "btn btn-
        danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> No </button> '
    });

    $('.btnPopover').on('click', function (e)
    {
        $('.btnPopover').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
```

Route:
`Route::get('remove/{id}', 'HomeController@removeFavourite');`

Controller (removeFavourite function):

```
public function removeFavourite($id)
{
    Favourites::where('id', $id)->delete();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Removed successfully!');
    return back();
}
```

The strange thing is, is that I am using the exact same function and JS call in another part of the application and it is working fine!

The problem is, that it deletes the last record belonging to that user in the database.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing some code so I can't tell for sure but it looks like where you are adding `$favorite->id` to the JS is likely after some php loop where you are adding favorites to the page.  So no matter what button you push, it's going to add the last favorite you looped through.

Comment: `$favorite->id` is the place to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your code looks like, but the problem is that your JS is only valid for the last iteration of the loop, which sounds like what you're experiencing.

To fix it, you can move the form inside the popover button so that you can get the correct form link:

Example (moving the form):

```
<a href="#"> <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btnPopover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content='<form style="display: inline;" action="{{ URL::to('remove', array($favourite->id)) }} "> <button class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok" onclick="return ConfirmDelete()"> Yes </button> </form> <button class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> No </button> '> Remove </button> </a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.btnPopover').popover(
    {
        html: 'true',
        title: '<strong> Are you sure you want to Remove? </strong>',
    });

    $('.btnPopover').on('click', function (e)
    {
        $('.btnPopover').not(this).popover('hide');
    });

    ....
```

This could be a little cleaner if you could access the parent button from the popover, but I couldn't find a way to do that in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the $id you retrieve in your program(I assume there is some code missing in the question which finds the $id) is the one you want to delete.

Answer (score -1):

Level official documentation says to use following code for deleting models:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->delete();
```

Find retrieves single model, and where returns a collection, so that might be the issue.

Also make sure that you pass the specific `$id` of the favourite that needs to be deleted, if not you'll always be deleting the last `$id` in your loop.

[Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models)